# C# - Удалённо получить все коммиты со всех веток

Tags: c#, git, git-remote

**Добрый день!**

Задался вопросом, как получить все коммиты со всех веток репозитория?
Пробовал использовать библиотеку LibGit2Sharp и командой git -ls remote вытянуть всё.
Но вытягиваются только все коммиты с ветки master, а нужно со всех веток.

Может кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой?

Comment: А как Вы себе это чисто в теории представляете? Например: Я себе на локальную машину ветку выведу. Как ее вытянуть?

Comment: Указанная выше задача называется clone.

Comment: @KoVadim я же написал удалённо. clone скачивает на локальную машину репозиторий. А мне нужно удалённо.

Comment: Все зависит от того, что Вы понимаете под "получить коммиты". Если только коммит сообщения - тогда это одно (и тут в принципе возможно). А если с содержимцм коммитов - тогда clone.